# Making Mobile view responsive in wso2 App Manager and EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I was trying to access the app store in WSO2 Appm as well as in EMM using my mobile device. Since I was redirected to the web view of the store, I was having problem to view properly on my device.

Can I customize the view of Appm and emm for accessing through mobile devices and make it compatible as mobile version? If yes, then how?

Comment: currently there is no way. if you want to access the app store in mobile device, there is a catalog app in the upcoming release.

Comment: what is the version that your using

Comment: For AppManager version is 1.1.0 and for EMM is 2.0.1

Comment: AppManger 1.2.0 release have responsive UI with support of boostrap3. which will be released within  2 months